# Send email on Bluehost shared hosting

Tags: laravel-5.4, bluehost, laravel-mail

I have tested Laravel emails on local server with gmail smtp and works fine.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myname@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I don't know how to find smtp details on bluhost shared hosting. So anyone knows the setting please comment.

This is what i have used currently on the server

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME=myname@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried with account of bluehost, this works:

```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=mail.domain.com
    MAIL_PORT=26
    MAIL_USERNAME=email@domain.com
    MAIL_PASSWORD=password
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```