# Laravel email sending is very slow

Tags: laravel, email

I have a site where i have used laravel email verification for user registration and other email sending functions . It works on localhost 
but when i upload it on bluehost 
It is running very slow like 
after about 1 to 2 hours only the email is going to the reciever email

I have used webmail and its driver for sending mail If i use Smtp it says Connection could not be establish and if i use sendmail driver the same thing happens email takes alot of time .

My .env configuration

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.openroomlist.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=support@openroomlist.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with ssl:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Or try this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mail.openroomlist.com
MAIL_PORT=26
MAIL_USERNAME=support@openroomlist.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Reference:

[Send email on Bluehost shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47525723/send-email-on-bluehost-shared-hosting)

More details about bluehost email sending:

https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/email-application-setup